What is a Node in ServiceNow CMDB
There are several definitions what a node represents in CMDB. The most often found are:

Nodes are used to map out the IT infrastructure, providing a clear
view of how components interact and depend on each other. This is
crucial for incident management, change management, and overall IT
Service management (including load, availability and performance).
A Node typically represents a Configuration Item (CI).

Questions are:

Is there really just a 1:1 relationship between CI and Node? I saw
several models “grouping” integrated 3rd party services via CG. So,
neither a 1:1 relationship with a CI nor to a CI at all.
If there is really just a 1:1 relationship between a node and a CI,
why does this help to get “a clear view of how components interact”?
Why not just using the CI itself?
A “useful” definition of a node and a link to a tutorial would be
very welcome.

